# How to sync Top Tabbar with ScrollView or List in swiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to implement the design here Top Tabbar with ScrollView or List so that when tabs are clicked then the ScrollView or List is scrolled to a particular position. I want the reverse procedure as well such that when the ScrollView or List is scrolled to a particular position then the particular tab is highlighted.

For example: If there are 4 tabs in the Top Tabbar and when ScrollView or List is scrolled to 3rd Cell (item visible and below Top Tabbar) then the 3rd tab should be highlighted.

[image]

Comment: You can use Scroll view reader

Comment: @lorem ipsum, Scroll view reader has only scrollTo method but does not have method get current scroll position.

Comment: If you search for finding the position of a SwiftUI ScrollView in SO you will find a few solutions out there. From using preference key to having an array of visible items and using the middle one as focus.